# Request problem while developing riot api using c#

Tags: c#, json

I got the unique id value normally, but
An error occurs in the second response request message. No answer was found for 5 hours.

---

```
 WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://kr.api.riotgames.com/lol/summoner/v4/summoners/by-name/"+summonerName+"?api_key=myKey");
 HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();

 Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
 StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
 string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
 dynamic data = JObject.Parse(responseFromServer);
                
 string id = data.id;
 string realid = id.ToString().Trim();



 WebRequest webRequest2 = WebRequest.Create("https://kr.api.riotgames.com/lol/league/v4/entries/by-summoner/"+realid+"?api_key=myKey");
 HttpWebResponse response2 = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest2.GetResponse();
 Stream dataStream2 = response2.GetResponseStream();
 StreamReader reader2 = new StreamReader(dataStream2);
 string responseFromServer2 = reader2.ReadToEnd();
 dynamic loldata = JObject.Parse(responseFromServer2); // <== truble
```

Comment: What's the value of responseFromServer2 ?

Comment: JArray legdata = JArray.Parse(responseFromServer2);  <== solution                    but foreach (JObject jobj in legdata)
    {
      model.partnerModel.LolTier =jobj["tier"].ToString();  ==> result                                 Get the value in the second list, not the value in the first list

Comment: i solved ==> legdata[0~1]["JProperty"].ToString();